# Running shell task in VSCode says "file not found"

Tags: visual-studio-code, task

I'm trying to create a custom shell task following the official documentation.

When running the task with CTRL+SHIFT+B, it returns

```
/usr/bin/bash: line 1: /usr/bin/daps-xmlformat: File not found
```

I cant see while the task cannot find the command when i supply the absolute path there?
Any ideas?

My code looks like this:

```
"tasks": [
            {
                "label": "Daps: XML format",
                "type": "shell",
                "command": "/usr/bin/daps-xmlformat",
                "args": ["${file}"],
                "group": "build",
                "presentation": {
                    "echo": true,
                    "reveal": "always",
                    "focus": false,
                    "panel": "shared",
                    "showReuseMessage": true,
                    "clear": true,
                    "close": false
                },
                "options": {
                    "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
                },
            }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the glitch. I was using the flatpak version of VSCodium and it has limited access to the host file system. RPM version works great.